# Sharepoint Online error when editing menu items (URL format)

Tags: permissions, error, url, menu

Been unable to edit our menu for a little while:
[image: SharePoint Error]

After a lot of searching around I found some reference to changing URL names. We did change our tenant's primary domain following a company name change, but the URL for SharePoint was not changed and has continued to work, it just won't let us edit the menu.

Any ideas?